# Рекурсивное вычитание (PHP)

Tags: php

Есть функция с рекурсивным вычитанием. На каждой рекурсии появляется промежуточный ответ (0, 1, 1 и 2). Что добавить в код, чтобы отображался не только окончательный ответ, но и промежуточные ответы?

```
<?php
function minus($n) {

    if ($n <=0) return;
    return $n - minus ($n-1);
}
echo minus(3);
?>
```

[image]

Добавил картинку с решением:

[image]

Comment: Добавьте `echo` в функцию. Или функция должна возвращать не значение, а массив значений. Потом выводить этот массив

Comment: Если добавить echo, то в этом случае будет возвращаться текущий аргумент, а необходим вывод каждой итерации рекурсии :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы обратить порядок вывода результатов, нужно делать вывод после рекурсивного спуска:

```
function minus($n) {
    if ($n <= 0) {
        echo "minus($n) = 0", PHP_EOL;
        return 0;
    }
    $res = $n - minus($n-1);
    echo "minus($n) = $res", PHP_EOL;
    return $res;
}
minus(3);
```

Результат:

> minus(0) = 0
>   minus(1) = 1
>   minus(2) = 1
>   minus(3) = 2

---

Можно отделить tracelog от вывода, передав массив для сохранения промежуточных результатов по ссылке:

```
function minus($n, &$log) {
    if ($n <= 0) {
        $log[] = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    $res = $n - minus($n-1, $log);
    $log[] = $res;
    return $res;
}

$log = [];
minus(3, $log);
echo implode(', ', $log); // 0, 1, 1, 2
```

Comment: Спасибо, маэстро!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function minus($n) {
    echo($n); // Все что необходимо.
    if ($n <=0) return;
    return $n - minus ($n-1);
}
echo minus(3);
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но в данном случае результат должен быть такой: 0, 1, 1, 2. А при Вашем способе получается 3, 2, 1, 0, 2. Есть ещё идеи?